# OnClickListener doesn't work in custom listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I try  to use `OnClickListener` in custom listview,But when textview clicked (Onclicklistener Run) It's runing code on several textview in listview!
see `holder.tvComment.setOnClickListener` in My `ListAdapter.class`  **Updated**:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.skyline.jimmy.widget.LikeToast;
import com.skyline.jimmy.widget.MyToast;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
//import android.text.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VoteListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected static final String CLIPBOARD_SERVICE = null;
    private final String TAG = "*** VoteListAdapter ***";
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Vote> votes;
    int showHideBtn = 0;
    public VoteListAdapter(Context context,List<Vote> voteList) {
        this.context =context;
        this.votes =(ArrayList<Vote>) voteList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return votes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return votes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder      = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder.tvName      = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user);
            holder.tvComment   = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvComment);
            holder.tvDate      = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tDate);
            holder.tvLikes      = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLikes);
            holder.ratingBar   = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            holder.share   = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);
            holder.copyJoke  = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.copyJoke);
            holder.btnLike  = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likebtn);
            holder.btnLiked  = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likedbtn);
            holder.btns   = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btns);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Typeface yaghut=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/Far_Casablanca.ttf");
        String likes = Integer.parseInt(votes.get(position).getRate()) + " likes";
        holder.tvName.setText(votes.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvComment.setText(votes.get(position).getComment());
        holder.tvDate.setText(getFormatedDate(votes.get(position).getPublishDate()));
        holder.tvLikes.setText(likes);
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(Integer.parseInt(votes.get(position).getRate()));
        holder.tvComment.setTypeface(yaghut);
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder.tvComment.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                int clicks = 0;
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    clicks = clicks + 1;
                    if(clicks == 1){

                    }else if(clicks == 2) {
                        LikeToast.makeText(context, "Liked" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        holder.btnLike.setText("Liked");
                        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_action_liked );
                        int hlike = image.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
                        int wlike = image.getIntrinsicWidth();   
                        image.setBounds( 0, 0, wlike, hlike );
                        holder.btnLike.setCompoundDrawables( image, null, null, null );
                        //holder.btnLikes.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_liked);
                    } else{
                       clicks = 2;
                   }
                }
            });
               convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        holder.btns.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                if(showHideBtn == 1){

                    holder.share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.btns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.copyJoke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    showHideBtn = 0;

                } else {

                    holder.share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.btns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.copyJoke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    showHideBtn = 1;
                }
            }
        });



        holder.copyJoke.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                String Joke = votes.get(position).getComment();
                clipboard.setText(Joke);

                Toast toast3 = MyToast.makeText(context, "جک مورد نظر کپی شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast3.show();

            }
        });

        holder.share.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               /* Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,votes.get(position).getComment());
                try {
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share"));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
               */

                Toast toast = MyToast.makeText(context, "این قسمت در نسخه بتا در حال طراحی است", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                Toast toast2 = MyToast.makeText(context, "منتظر آپدیت باشید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast2.show();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }




    private String getFormatedDate(String date) {
        String myDate = null;

        try {
            Date oldDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(date);
            myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(oldDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            myDate = "";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return myDate;
    }



    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageButton copyJoke;
        ImageButton share;
        ImageButton btns;
        Button btnLike;
        Button btnLiked;
        TextView  tvName;
        TextView  tvLikes;
        TextView  tvComment;
        TextView  tvDate;
        RatingBar ratingBar;
    }
}
```

Comment: remove setFocusable and setFocusableInTouchMode for btns.. And try..

Comment: @ArpitPatel I try but it Doesnt matter

Answer (score 0):

write your setOnClickListener code into the if condition

```
if (convertView == null) {
   .....
   .....
   // write here your holder.tvComment.setOnClickListener

   convertView.setTag(holder);
}
```

and before this line:

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

**Your full adapter would be something like this:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.skyline.jimmy.widget.LikeToast;
import com.skyline.jimmy.widget.MyToast;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
//import android.text.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VoteListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ViewHolder holder;
    protected static final String CLIPBOARD_SERVICE = null;
    private final String TAG = "*** VoteListAdapter ***";
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Vote> votes;
    int showHideBtn = 0;
    public VoteListAdapter(Context context,List<Vote> voteList) {
        this.context =context;
        this.votes =(ArrayList<Vote>) voteList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return votes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return votes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder      = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder.tvName      = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user);
            holder.tvComment   = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvComment);
            holder.tvDate      = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tDate);
            holder.tvLikes      = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLikes);
            holder.ratingBar   = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            holder.share   = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);
            holder.copyJoke  = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.copyJoke);
            holder.btnLike  = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likebtn);
            holder.btnLiked  = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likedbtn);
            holder.btns   = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btns);


            holder.btns.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    if(showHideBtn == 1){

                        holder.share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.btns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.copyJoke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        showHideBtn = 0;

                    } else {

                        holder.share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.btns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.copyJoke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        showHideBtn = 1;
                    }
                }
            });



        holder.copyJoke.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                String Joke = votes.get(position).getComment();
                clipboard.setText(Joke);

                Toast toast3 = MyToast.makeText(context, "جک مورد نظر کپی شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast3.show();

            }
        });

        holder.share.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               /* Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,votes.get(position).getComment());
                try {
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share"));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
               */

                Toast toast = MyToast.makeText(context, "این قسمت در نسخه بتا در حال طراحی است", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                Toast toast2 = MyToast.makeText(context, "منتظر آپدیت باشید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast2.show();
            }
        });


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Typeface yaghut=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/Far_Casablanca.ttf");
        String likes = Integer.parseInt(votes.get(position).getRate()) + " likes";
        holder.tvName.setText(votes.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvComment.setText(votes.get(position).getComment());
        holder.tvDate.setText(getFormatedDate(votes.get(position).getPublishDate()));
        holder.tvLikes.setText(likes);
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(Integer.parseInt(votes.get(position).getRate()));
        holder.tvComment.setTypeface(yaghut);


        return convertView;
    }

    private String getFormatedDate(String date) {
        String myDate = null;

        try {
            Date oldDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(date);
            myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(oldDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            myDate = "";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return myDate;
    }



    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageButton copyJoke;
        ImageButton share;
        ImageButton btns;
        Button btnLike;
        Button btnLiked;
        TextView  tvName;
        TextView  tvLikes;
        TextView  tvComment;
        TextView  tvDate;
        RatingBar ratingBar;
    }
}
```

Comment: now OnCliclListener Doesn't work and eclipse show `Dead Code`! :(

Comment: remove this line: holder.tvComment.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); this code work for me

Comment: I try , but its say dead code !! I update my post plz see my code again :-(

Comment: tnx bro , but when I click tvComment should to change tvlikes background , it changed but some other rows in listview changed too ! I really dont know what to work :-(

Comment: Sry I cant Becuase I Should be have 15 reputation ! :| But when I Have 15 reputation (!) I vote up you :D !!!

Comment: Teacher :D , I do that but when I use setVisibility or setText I cant delete final keyword :(((

Comment: In any case, if I delete final keyword setVisibilty or setTexts have an error "Sould Use Final" !!

Comment: :-( I'm really disappointed in my programming :| :D . it doesn't work , no problem :(( , but Can I send project source to you plz :( :D